# Trying to download/install any python libraries

Tags: python, windows, coding-style

So I'm working on an app in VS Code and I'm trying to install the (pillow) and (kivy) libraries in python and I always get this same error. Does anyone have any answers to this. It would be greatly appreciated!!

The first line below is what I type into the terminal in VS Code.

python -m pip install kivy[full]

Collecting kivy[full]
Downloading Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 23.8/23.8 MB 7.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [9 lines of output]
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
Downloading Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
-------------------------------------- 983.8/983.8 kB 3.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Everything listed above!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you’re missing some gstreamer libraries that Kivy depends on. A quick google search led me to the PyPi package that matches what it’s asking for. Looks like the current version is 0.4 so you will need to specify 0.3.3 when you install via pip. PyPi package: [gstreamer dep](https://pypi.org/project/kivy-deps.gstreamer-dev/)

Edit: [Here](https://pypi.org/project/kivy-deps.gstreamer-dev/0.3.3/) is the exact version with the pip install command. Hope this helps.

Comment: It said that it can't find the version. I am using Python 3.10.8 I saw a mention of someone saying that kivy isn't supported by Python3.10 and you must use Python3.9 or lower. Is this true

Comment: I don't know since I've never used Kivy. But you can try installing python3.9. Look up how to install python3.9 on your os. Then create a new python virtualenvironment and specify python3.9 as your interpretter using `virtualenv -p python3.9 venv`. Try installing the required packages and running your program again.